# Delete a file "older than" in a zip archive

Tags: linux, bash, unix, zip, archive

I am archiving once a month a file that is 10 MB and then emailing it.
Next month, I need to delete the previous months file IN the archive and add the new one. That way I keep the space to a low. Other than unarchiving and searching and then archiving, I haven't found a way to do it!

The filename ends with date of the last month. filename20130430.csv and the date is the variable date.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not simply keep your files stored as is, and create each month a new archive you'll send by email ? (and then you can eventually delete the archive file)

Comment: I will have to do that eventually. If there is no other way.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [info ZIP](http://www.info-zip.org/), you can selectively delete files from an archive with "-d", eg:

```
zip -d archive.zip filename201304\*.csv
```

You can also delete files depending on their modification date (note that the date format is either mmddyyyy or yyyy-mm-dd), eg. delete all csv files before May 1st 2013:

```
zip --before-date 05012013 -d archive.zip \*.csv
```

and add a file to the archive without any option:

```
zip archive.zip filename20130531.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

To preserve disk space you may just convert all CSV files into ZIP:

```
# ZIP all CSV files older than 14 days within the same directory
find /your/directory/*.csv -mtime +13 -execdir zip -rm ./'{}'\.zip '{}' \;
```

See manual on [find -execdir](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) and [zip -rm](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip).